# Finding the largest number in an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods

I am trying to recursively find the largest element in an array. The user has to input the number of elements that the array will have. My error is that if that the list does not have an element which is larger than the number of elements in the list, the output of the largest number will be the number of elements in the list. eg: array of 5 integers containing {1 1 1 2 3}. the answer will be 5 and not 3.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test7 {

    public static int findLargest(int[] a, int max) {

        int i=0, j=0, tempmax=0;
        if (a.length == 1) return a[0]>max ? a[0]:max;
        else if(max < a[i]){
            max = a[i];
            int[] tempArr = new int[a.length -1];
            for (i=1; i<a.length; i++){
                tempArr[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
            tempmax = findLargest(tempArr, max);
            return tempmax;
        }
        else{
            int[] tempArr = new int[a.length -1];
            for (i=1; i<a.length; i++){
                tempArr[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
            tempmax = findLargest(tempArr, max);
            return tempmax;
        }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = new int[100];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in your list: ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        if(x>1 || x<100){
            for (int i=0; i<=(x-1); i++){
                System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
                System.out.println();
                values[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }       
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The largest number is: "+findLargest(values, x));
        }
        else System.out.println("The maximum number of elements must be less than 100");


    }
}
```

Comment: Should you not be calling the method with `findLargest(values, 0)` at all times except recursively? Meaning, the first call should pass 0 as the current max (or perhaps the smallest possible int value)

Comment: If recursivity is not important, you can choose the lazy and short way: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/Minimumandmaximumnumberinarray.htm

Answer (score 2):

You call your method with:

```
System.out.println("The largest number is: "+findLargest(values, x))
```

This tells it to assume the largest number is `x` and try to find anything in the list that is greater than that. Of course, this produces the exact problem you described.

In general, when finding a maximum number, you want to initialize your candidate to the lowest number possible, or to the first number in your array.

If you initialize to the lowest number possible (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`) then as soon as you start your algorithm, the first number will definitely be bigger than it and will be chosen as the next candidate for maximum.

If you initialize to the first item in your array, then if that number is the highest, all well and good. If it is not, then when you encounter the next higher number, it will become the candidate, and all is good.

Which one you choose is up to you (and depends also on whether an empty array is possible), but the thing to remember is never to select an initial candidate that might be greater than all the elements in the array.

Comment: @denbuttigieg If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it (clicking the checkmark) - this is the StackOverflow way of saying "Thanks, that helped".

Answer (score 0):

Try this working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = {2, 5134, 333, 123, 8466};

    int largest = numbers[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        largest = Math.max(largest, numbers[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Largest number: "+largest);
}
```

As a method that would look like this:

```
public static int max(int first, int... more)
{
    for(int element:more)
    {
        first = Math.max(first, element);
    }

    return first;
}
```

You can then call it using something like `max(1,23,564,234,543);`

Comment: thanks a lot for this, but i need to compute the .max method.

Comment: so you want that as a varargs method?